# How are image sensor (camera) based controllers implemented?

Tags: optimization, control-theory, image-processing, optimal-control, linear-control

How are image sensor (camera) based controllers implemented?

I am planning to design a control system where I am taking feedback using a camera. With the techniques I know I feel it will take considerable amount of time in processing the image and acquiring features from it. I would like to know how exactly are these implemented on real time?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you narrow down your question a bit? This is a very broad subject area.

Comment: I would like to get some good references from which I can understand how to implement feedback control using images?

Answer (score 1):

You can find some slides on the subject over here:
- http://www.ics.ele.tue.nl/~heco/courses/EmbeddedVisualControl/

Direct links:
http://www.ics.ele.tue.nl/~heco/courses/EmbeddedVisualControl/EVC_Control_Basics-DipGoswami.pdf

http://www.ics.ele.tue.nl/~heco/courses/EmbeddedVisualControl/CV_lecture-EgorBondarau.pptx

http://www.ics.ele.tue.nl/~heco/courses/EmbeddedVisualControl/visual-servo-control.pdf